# LOB apps in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, business-intelligence, cloud-business-apps

I have been playing around with the SharePoint 2013 app model lately.
Maybe it is because I used to build Farm soltuions for on premise installations, but I miss the opportunity to build LOB apps for SharePoint Online.
Do I just have to get used to the model or is Microsoft making it harder for Devs to write big business apps?

In a lot of scenarios I would like to have an admin how configures an app. Then the users can use the app with the settings the admin has set for them. Is such a scenario even possible in SharePoint online?

What about SharePoint Designer and Workflows. I know that i can still use all these features inside my app web, but some of my applications give the customer the freedom of customize the workflows for example. This cannot be done as the SPD cannot access anything inside the web.

So my question is: Are realy LOB apps possible in the SharePoint cloud?

best regards
Alex

Comment: Using Provider hosted apps, you can write a .Net MVC app for example. With your own permissions, settings etc.